# What does this light-emitting pillar do?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I'm playing the Necropolis campaign in Might and Magic Heroes 6, and I noticed this pillar/tower-like thing on the battlefields. It seems to have some sort of light coming from it and landing on a specific square.

[image]

Am I going to get any bonuses (or debuffs) if I put one of my units there? Would any unit types benefit from it more than others?

Comment: You can right-click on it to get the details.  I believe that one gives you a mana bonus to your hero if a unit is in the glowing square.

Comment: @JasonBerkan I tried to right-click it and nothing happened. Guess I didn't click the right thing. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's no pillar - it's a Blind Maiden! In combat, it functions similarly to its adventure map counterpart by giving any unit in the glowing square bonus Destiny (Luck from past games).

[image]

^This is the adventure map version.

Jason Berkan gives sound advice: right-click all the things to find out what they are!